# Get value from second highest row, join SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables

#### Ranking

Columns: category_id, country_id, item_name, rank, created_at, updated_at, change

Pk: (category_id,country_id,rank)

#### Ranking_History

id, category_id, country_id, item_name, rank, created_at, updated_at

Pk: id

Ranking table contains current ranking, and Ranking History table contains all the rankings from the past. Rankings are updated everyday,I am unable to figure out the sql query to find change in ranking since the last ranking. `change` needs to be updated in the Rankings table.

I have tried joining table, but I only need one row from the ranking history table, but I can't restrict that during join.

Comment: I don't understand your problem, and more specifically, what `change` is.  Consider adding sample data that illustrates your input and your desired output.

Comment: Your primary key should probably use `item_name`, not `rank`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  why item_name? (rank, category_id, country_id) is also unique, There is only one item at each rank.

Comment: Consider a table schema adjustment here. Why are you recording ids, item_name, and rank twice in different related tables? Normalize for distinct items and multiple rank (one-to-many) and avoid repeating columns.

Comment: @rajat . . . `ranking` is a calculation that changes over time.  `item_name` seems more fundamental as the primary key for the table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff A entry with two different item_name but same rank, category_id, country_id is not a valid entry in my case, in my case a combination of  rank, category_id, county_id should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use date functions.  Something like this:

```
update ranking r
    set change = (r.rank = rh.rank)
    from ranking_history rh
    where r.category_id = rh.cateogry_id and
          r.country_id = rh.country_id and
          r.item_name = rh.item_name and
          date_trunc('day', r.created_at) = date_trunc('day', rh.created_at + interval '1 day');
```